# Add condition in router to navigate accordingly in Aurelia

Tags: aurelia

I am quite new to Aurelia and found it great in usage, my requirement is manage route conditionally like if I have token in my local-storage and I need to go straight to home and if there is not token than application goes to landingpage or login page.

I tried to find out but no success, I believe I have missed any proper term, what in my mind was like in angularJS (Parent route having `resolve` where we can decide where to redirect on basis of some condition e.g. `token`) OR in Angular it has `canActivate` where we can check some condition and manage route.

Looking something similar, will be great if any article or doc link can e shared

Thanks

Comment: you have the same mechanism in aurelia . [canActivate](https://aurelia.io/docs/api/router/interface/RoutableComponentCanActivate/method/canActivate/) is a function that you can have on your VM (one that is loaded by the router). or configure a [`preActivate`](https://aurelia.io/docs/routing/configuration#router-events) step - to all routes.

Comment: [Router Pipelines](https://aurelia.io/docs/routing/configuration#pipelines) can do the trick.

Comment: For this use-case, using Router Pipelines is recommended over canActivate as it's more centralized